# Grep a log file for SQL queries and their execution time

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep, cut

I have an application log file that also captures the execution time for each executed SQL statement, like below:-

**Sample logs:**

```
I 2023-11-15 07:18:00.743Z 1760463 37 ZVRwqItu6aw-b8eejMLI_gAAAAU 1@45077318@A PHP Request Summary: 7 warnings/errors on 6 lines
I 2023-11-15 07:17:15.927Z 1773299 99 ZVRwenUWDwrXl_9NnC-2vwAAAAM 1@45077318@A There is no cache key assigned for the current PID
I 2023-11-15 07:17:55.778Z 1773397 24 ZVRwoydG6PTd3KWR_MnfVAAAABU - Initiating db proxy socket to dev01:8080
I 2023-11-15 07:17:55.865Z 1773397 33 ZVRwoydG6PTd3KWR_MnfVAAAABU 1@45077318@A execStmtEx: time: 0.002 / 0 rows: 1 sql: <some_plsql_statement>
I 2023-11-15 07:17:56.185Z 1773397 65 ZVRwoydG6PTd3KWR_MnfVAAAABU 1@45077318@A applicationConnection TRX Record Commit (execStmtEx) time: 0
I 2023-11-15 07:17:57.515Z 1755787 26 ZVRwpA5grkn1knR4gk6FMwAAABA 1@45077318@A queryResults: time: 0.001 / 0 rows: 1 sql: <some_sql_here>
I 2023-11-15 07:17:57.519Z 1755787 26 ZVRwpA5grkn1knR4gk6FMwAAABA 1@45077318@A queryResults: time: 0.001 / 0 rows: 0 sql: <some_sql_here>
I 2023-11-15 07:17:57.529Z 1755787 27 ZVRwpA5grkn1knR4gk6FMwAAABA 1@45077318@A queryResults: time: 0.002 / 0 rows: 1 sql: <some_sql_here>
I 2023-11-15 07:17:57.531Z 1755787 27 ZVRwpA5grkn1knR4gk6FMwAAABA 1@45077318@A queryResults: time: 0.001 / 0 rows: 0 <some_sql_here>
I 2023-11-15 07:17:57.535Z 1755787 28 ZVRwpA5grkn1knR4gk6FMwAAABA 1@45077318@A queryResults: time: 0.002 / 0 rows: 1 sql: <some_sql_here>
I 2023-11-15 07:17:57.542Z 1755787 28 ZVRwpA5grkn1knR4gk6FMwAAABA 1@45077318@A queryResults: time: 0.002 / 0 rows: 1 sql: <some_sql_here>
...
```

I want to grep for all these SQL queries along with their execution times, sorted in descending order(based on their execution times).

**Desired output:**

```
time: 0.002 | sql: <some_plsql_statement>
time: 0.002 | sql: <some_sql_here>
```

How can I achieve this with Linux commands? Could someone please help me to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the file contain other lines too? If so please include a sample of those so we can see how to build a pattern that extracts only the relevant lines. (Right now `sort` would process the lines directly - no need for `grep` at all.)

Comment: @ChrisDavies, sorry for the late response, yes file contains other entries also related to the application. Could you please update your answer accordingly?

Comment: @ArpitJain no, please update your _question_ accordingly. We cannot help you parse data that you don't show us. Also, please [edit] and explain how you want the output sorted. In descending order, yes, but of what? Of the time the command took to execute? Of the time it was launched? Alphabetically? Basically, show us a more complete example of your input, including lines you do not want to keep, and then show us the output you would want from that example.

Comment: @terdon, log file can contain many entries, I tried to add few, please let me know if that helps. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, that helps, but adding the expected output would be even better.

Comment: Basically, i want to grep for all the time-consuming process and analyze them.

Comment: Yes, so please show us. Will all the input lines have exactly the same format? Can we expect the time to always be the 10th field? Or do you mean the time at the 3rd field?

Comment: Should data from `I 2023-11-15 07:17:57.531Z 1755787 27 ZVRwpA5grkn1knR4gk6FMwAAABA 1@45077318@A queryResults: time: 0.001 / 0 rows: 0 <some_sql_here>` (which doesn't contain `sql:`) appear in the output? How about `I 2023-11-15 07:17:55.865Z 1773397 33 ZVRwoydG6PTd3KWR_MnfVAAAABU 1@45077318@A execStmtEx: time: 0.002 / 0 rows: 1 sql: <some_plsql_statement>` which apparently isn't a result of a query as you said you wanted (doesn't contain `queryResults`)? How about a line containing text like `... this :foosql: stuff sucks`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide sample input that doesn't just cover your sunny day cases and show the exact expected output from the sample input you post or you're likely to get an answer that will only work for your sunny day cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your lines will always have the same number of fields, and that `sql:` will only appear on the lines you want, you can do this to sort on the 10th field which seems to be the time it took to run the command:

```
$ grep sql: log | sort -rnk 10,10
I 2023-11-15 07:17:57.542Z 1755787 28 ZVRwpA5grkn1knR4gk6FMwAAABA 1@45077318@A queryResults: time: 0.002 / 0 rows: 1 sql: <some_sql_here>
I 2023-11-15 07:17:57.535Z 1755787 28 ZVRwpA5grkn1knR4gk6FMwAAABA 1@45077318@A queryResults: time: 0.002 / 0 rows: 1 sql: <some_sql_here>
I 2023-11-15 07:17:57.529Z 1755787 27 ZVRwpA5grkn1knR4gk6FMwAAABA 1@45077318@A queryResults: time: 0.002 / 0 rows: 1 sql: <some_sql_here>
I 2023-11-15 07:17:55.865Z 1773397 33 ZVRwoydG6PTd3KWR_MnfVAAAABU 1@45077318@A execStmtEx: time: 0.002 / 0 rows: 1 sql: <some_plsql_statement>
I 2023-11-15 07:17:57.519Z 1755787 26 ZVRwpA5grkn1knR4gk6FMwAAABA 1@45077318@A queryResults: time: 0.001 / 0 rows: 0 sql: <some_sql_here>
I 2023-11-15 07:17:57.515Z 1755787 26 ZVRwpA5grkn1knR4gk6FMwAAABA 1@45077318@A queryResults: time: 0.001 / 0 rows: 1 sql: <some_sql_here>
```

Or, if you want to sort on the 3rd field which I am guessing is the time the command was executed, use:

```
$ grep sql: log | sort -rnk 3,3
I 2023-11-15 07:17:57.542Z 1755787 28 ZVRwpA5grkn1knR4gk6FMwAAABA 1@45077318@A queryResults: time: 0.002 / 0 rows: 1 sql: <some_sql_here>
I 2023-11-15 07:17:57.535Z 1755787 28 ZVRwpA5grkn1knR4gk6FMwAAABA 1@45077318@A queryResults: time: 0.002 / 0 rows: 1 sql: <some_sql_here>
I 2023-11-15 07:17:57.529Z 1755787 27 ZVRwpA5grkn1knR4gk6FMwAAABA 1@45077318@A queryResults: time: 0.002 / 0 rows: 1 sql: <some_sql_here>
I 2023-11-15 07:17:57.519Z 1755787 26 ZVRwpA5grkn1knR4gk6FMwAAABA 1@45077318@A queryResults: time: 0.001 / 0 rows: 0 sql: <some_sql_here>
I 2023-11-15 07:17:57.515Z 1755787 26 ZVRwpA5grkn1knR4gk6FMwAAABA 1@45077318@A queryResults: time: 0.001 / 0 rows: 1 sql: <some_sql_here>
I 2023-11-15 07:17:55.865Z 1773397 33 ZVRwoydG6PTd3KWR_MnfVAAAABU 1@45077318@A execStmtEx: time: 0.002 / 0 rows: 1 sql: <some_plsql_statement>
```

And if you only want the text from `time:` to the end of the line, assuming GNU `grep`, do:

```
$ grep -o 'time:.* sql:.*' log | sort -rnk 2,2
time: 0.002 / 0 rows: 1 sql: <some_sql_here>
time: 0.002 / 0 rows: 1 sql: <some_sql_here>
time: 0.002 / 0 rows: 1 sql: <some_sql_here>
time: 0.002 / 0 rows: 1 sql: <some_plsql_statement>
time: 0.001 / 0 rows: 1 sql: <some_sql_here>
time: 0.001 / 0 rows: 0 sql: <some_sql_here>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, could you please also add some details like how it works with each command so it would help me to understand and modify if needed, I would really appreciate that.

Comment: @ArpitJain there is nothing special here. Just look at `man grep` and `man sort`, and read the documentation for the options I am using. The `-o` tells `grep` to only print the matching section of the line, the `-n` tells `sort` to sort numerically and the `-r` to sort in reverse order. The `-k n,n` means "only sort on field n".

Comment: `grep sql: log | sort -rnk 2,2`, here in your answer it should be 10,10 if we want to sort on the 10th field?

Comment: @ArpitJain eeeek! Sorry! I had a copy/paste error. Please see updated answer. Yes, you want `-k 10,10` to sort on the 10th field (if you use `-k 10` it sorts _from_ the 10th field and until the end of the line; with `10,10` it sorts _only_ on the 10th).

Comment: You're welcome. And it starts from 1.

Comment: Sorting by the clock time only will mix up results for multiple dates - I'd suggest using `-k 2,3` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Extract the relevant fields, printing only lines that match, and sort the result by descending time of execution:

```
sed -En 's/^.*(time: [0-9.]+) .* (sql: .*)/\1 | \2/p' logfile | sort -k2,3nr
```

Output

```
time: 0.002 | sql: <some_plsql_statement>
time: 0.002 | sql: <some_sql_here>
time: 0.002 | sql: <some_sql_here>
time: 0.002 | sql: <some_sql_here>
time: 0.001 | sql: <some_sql_here>
time: 0.001 | sql: <some_sql_here>
```